# VBA copy pasting

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a VBA which copy and paste data from one sheet to another. The VBA only works for on row which data is in sheet2. I need the VBA to automatically go to the next row. It needs to do that until there is no data in the next row. In the example down below it's already after 3 rows.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIHpM.png)

```
Sub goeie()
    With Sheets("A")

    'bord 2 verwijzingen
    .[C42].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[4]C[13]"
    .[D42].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[4]C[10]"
    .[E42].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[4]C[10]"
    .[F42].FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(blad2!R[4]C[11]=""S235"",235,355)"

    'bord 1 verwijzingen
    .[C43].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[3]C[9]"
    .[D43].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[3]C[6]"
    .[E43].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[3]C[6]"
    .[F43].FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(blad2!R[3]C[7]=""S235"",235,355)"

    'deur
    .[C56].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[-10]C[3]"
    .[D56].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[-10]C[1]"
    .[E56].FormulaR1C1 = "=blad2!R[-10]C[2]"
    .[F56].FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(blad2!R[3]C[2]=""V"",""X-as"",""Y-as"")"
    End With

    With Sheets("Blad2")
    .[R46].FormulaR1C1 = "=A!R[12]C[1]"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Offset to do this

example:

```
     pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Value
     pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Value
     pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = .Value
```

I included multiple examples so that you know how to navigate between columns and rows :)    Offset(rows,columns)